# Configure CKEditor to encode pasted images as base 64 jpg not png

Tags: ckeditor, base64, xpages, lotus-notes

I have an application with an X-Page that provides general users a simple interface for submitting requests to IT. This X-Page has a rich text editor (using the CKEditor) and allows them to paste images (so they can include screenshots).

The IT staff access the applications through the Notes client (v8.5) using a traditional Notes form with a Rich text field. My system is specially configured with Notes 9 as we are looking to move to that in the near future.

In the Notes 9 client, the screenshots submitted by the X-Page appear correctly in the traditional Notes form's rich text field. However users with the 8.5 client get the box with the red X for the screenshots.

From my research I believe that this is because of the way the CK Editor encodes the image as a base 64 MIME png. I think that the 8.5 client is having trouble rendering the png whereas the 9 client is able to render it correctly.

Does anyone know if there is:

a) a setting in the Notes 8.5 client that may be preventing the images appearing correctly (or will let it render png)

or

b) is there a way I can configure the CK Editor to encode the images as base 64 MIME jpg or gif instead of png?

Comment: Hi Becca, we faced a similar problem, related to the fact that pasted images in CKEditor are by default images with a 'data url'
Data url images are not compatible with all types of clients.
Our solution was to intercept the paste event, and upload the image using the same 'image upload' mechanism that's used by the image button on the CKEditor toolbar. This uploads the image as a separate mime entity and is better supported. Another option is to prevent pasting images altogether. I don't have time to write specifics now but if no one does I will provide a more detailed answer next week

Comment: @CameronGregor ooh, please share the code that intercepts the pasted image 

Comment: no prob I will share next week. Becca, after reading Karl-Henry's answer I am not sure if my solution will help as it is still PNG. what happens if you insert a PNG using the normal insert image toolbar icon? does that show ok in 8.5? if it shows ok my solution will help

Comment: Thanks for your response @CameronGregor. I will need to get my hands on an 8.5. client and check. (proving to be more difficult here than I'd hoped :-( ) I don't want to turn off pasting images if I can help it as the whole point of the changes was to allow them to do so.

Comment: No prob, let me know how you go!

Comment: Hi @CameronGregor, I finally managed to get my hands on an 8.5 client to run some tests and sure enough, your suspicion was correct. The PNGs load fine if they are from the insert image toolbar icon. Could you please post your code so I can see if it would work for me? TIA

Comment: No prob Becca I just need to pull the plugin out of our codebase and test it on a 'blank' database to make sure it it will work, I will do it as soon as I get a chance

Comment: @CameronGregor do you have an idea of when you might be able to get to this at all?

Comment: Hi Becca, are you in the XPages slack chat? is it possible I can talk to you about this in private, I can't share the solution publicly just yet but am happy to explain how to do it in private. you can also find me on twitter

Comment: Didn't know it existed. Signing up now.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, Notes 8.x does not support PNG fully. It is supported in some places, but failing in other:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21368274
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21090737
Notes 8.5 came out in 2008, try to speed up the move to 9.0.1 and the problem goes away. :-)

Comment: This seems to indicate that PNGs should work in 8.5.x, which I contrary to what I read on the Notes forums with issues up until around 8.5.2. Granted IBM only ever mention email messages, but I assume this translates to other rich text fields as well. I really wish I could speed up the 9.0.1 roll out, but unfortunately it is out of my hands.